# How can I decrement numbers in Collatz conjecture program in C

Tags: c, loops

Currently I am implementing the Collatz conjecture problem in the C language. I am able to print the series of a particular digit. For instance if number is `25` then series is something like `25 76 38 19 58 29 88 44 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 = 24`. `24` is the number of elements in the series. Now I want to print the number of series till `1`. like `25,24,...` to `1`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long x, a = 0;

    printf("Enter the value of X:");
    scanf("%lu", &x);
    printf("%ld ", x);

    for (i = x * x; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            x = x / 2;
            printf("%lu ", x);
            if (x == 1) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            x = (3 * x) + 1;
            printf("%lu ", x);
            if (x == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }   
        a++;
    }
    printf(" = %lu\n", a + 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: A debugger is a very important tool in your toolbox. Using a debugger you can step through code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill needed for anyone who want to program, even as a part-time hobbyist.

Comment: Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to tell us what input you give the program, what its actual output is, and what output you expected.

Comment: You need nested loop.(2 loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an extra loop to iterate from `x` down to `1`.

Note that your code does not work correctly for the value `1` and does not count the number of outputs at the right spot, leading to a surprising `+ 2` final adjustment.

Moving the code to a separate function would improve readability.

Your guard loop does not make sense: stopping after `x * x` iterations assumes `x * x` is in the range of `unsigned long`, which can be very low (`x < 65536` on Windows). larger values might give an incorrect result. Just removing the guard test simplifies the code and if we assume the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) to be true (It has been tested for all starting values up to 2<sup>60</sup>) any counter examples yielding an infinite loop would be welcome.

Here is a simplified and extended version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long xx, x, a;

    printf("Enter the value of X: ");
    if (scanf("%lu", &xx) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (; xx >= 1; xx--) {
        x = xx;
        a = 0;
        for (;;) {
            printf("%lu ", x);
            a++;
            if (x == 1)
                break;
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                x = x / 2;
            } else {
                x = (3 * x) + 1;
            }
        }
        printf("= %lu\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to have the Collatz function for 1 element in a function. This function would take a parameter of the element that e.g. 25 and then print the collatz series for 25.

You can then run a loop around that function calling it with parameter 24, 23, 22 etc. This will give the collatz series for all those numbers.

I am not giving the code, as you should try it out for yourself.